# Error due to android toast message being started in the wrong thread

Tags: android, toast

Hi I'm having some problems to show a toast message, actually the program crash saying that I'm trying to disply a toast in the wrong thread or something like that.

I have been reading some other questions about the topic and I think the soultions is something like using a handler to comunicate with the UI, but not sure how to do it, could any one share with me an example/tutorial about how to launch a toast mesage from any part of the code?

For example I'm trying something like this: [the problematic line is between** **]

```
public class SamplesTiming extends Activity {
        ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_samples_timing);
       ...

    }

        private void setButtonHandlers() {
                ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        }

        private void enableButton(int id,boolean isEnable){
                ((Button)findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
        }

        private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
                enableButton(R.id.btnStart,!isRecording);
                enableButton(R.id.btnStop,isRecording);
        }



        private void startRecording(){

                              ...

                recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        //@Override
                        public void run() {

                                writeAudioDataToFile();
                        }
                },"AudioRecorder Thread");

                recordingThread.start();
        }


        private void writeAudioDataToFile(){

               ...

                while(isRecording){

                             ...

                        read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);


                        if(condition) **Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                           "it happen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();**

                            ...

                        }                       


        }

        private void stopRecording(){
                if(null != recorder){
                        isRecording = false;

                        recorder.stop();
                        recorder.release();

                        recorder = null;
                        recordingThread = null;
                }                  

        }


        private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
               // @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        switch(v.getId()){
                                case R.id.btnStart:{



                                    enableButtons(true);
                                        startRecording();

                                        break;
                                }
                                case R.id.btnStop:{


                                        enableButtons(false);
                                        stopRecording();

                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                }
        };
}
```

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: "or something like that" is a very specific exception, and you'll find the solution by simply googling "something like that" (first answer)

Comment: Wow you are a really useful member, hope you win the prize to the funniest member on here. Good luck ;)

Comment: just trying to point out that your question was not containing much information to help it's resolved. Also trying to say that i don't get why you would ask about "something like that" rather than posting the complete error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Activity.runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for showing Toast from background thread as :

```
while(isRecording){

......

SamplesTiming.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         // show toast here
         Toast.makeText(SamplesTiming.this, 
            "it happen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
.....

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It must in the main thread if you want to access the widgets.
You can write follows if you are in an Activity.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //toast
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me and you dislike convenience methods, use a `Handler`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        doSomethingOnAnotherThread();
    }

    private void doSomethingOnAnotherThread() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "toast skagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I really need to learn how to use handlers, because I'm still having serious problems to make them work.